# How do I suppress a warning in the IDE in Python? (IDE is Jupyter)

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, runtime-error, suppress-warnings

Is there a simple way to hide an error in the IDE printout?

```
logts = np.log(ts)
plt.plot(logts, amps, "1", ms=10)
```

Is my relevant section of code. Due to `ts` containing a 0 as its first point, Python isn't overly fond of the `np.log(ts)` operation. The IDE (Jupyter) throws an error message

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:119: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log

But the rest of the code runs fine, the relevant pair of results (the ts = 0, and respective `amps` value are removed later anyway when plotting best fit lines to stop problems with infinities. But I would still like to supress that specific error message, since I know what's causing it and it's otherwise fine.

Comment: I think there's probably something in there that will help, but I must confess being fairly new to all this, I don't really understand how to implement most of it, and attempt to implement it, didn't work for me.

Comment: If you are not using or showing the result anyway, why not simply discard the zeros before calculating the logarithm?

Comment: I wasn't really sure how to do that, and discard the respective 'amps' result. I only really managed it the other way with some help from another post on another question. I am very early on in learning anything in python, so... bit by bit... I did try initial but many of the ways I tried either resulted in the code not running or really throwing off the graph at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
import warnings; 
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

at the start of your program to ignore all warnings.

---

If you want to ignore only that specific warning then use "seterr"

```py
np.seterr(divide = 'ignore') 
logts = np.log(ts)
np.seterr(divide = 'warn')
```

Comment: Will this ignore all warnings or just that specific one (which is what I am aiming to do)?

Comment: It might be easier to write any code in by editting the main answer than trying to write it in the comments. At least in my experience

Comment: see the improved answer.

Comment: yes, but if you are doing a big project then it will become a boring task to comment & uncomment lines if you need that variables again.

Comment: That did it. Thank you, for both answers. At the moment my program is only about 147 lines, probably 120 actually have text, so you're right, I will likely need to use the larger scale ones as the project size increases. For now commenting is not too bad. Thank you.